# Convert Hex into ASCII character

Tags: networking, hex, ascii, protocols, packets

I am reading Head First Networking and there is a part that shows a packet with many information, and my mission is decode that packet, i.e get the Protocol Type, Destination IP Address and Source IP Address. 
Said that, I have the following info:

```
Protocol Type:                 0x01  (ICMP)
Destination IP Address:        cc 3e cb 0d = 204.62.203.13 (getting Ì>Ë)
Source IP Address:             c0 a8 01 2f = 192.168.1.41  (getting À¨/)
```

I tried to convert the Destination & Source IP Address online using Hex to ASCII but I am not receiving expected results as shown above. I also searched in the ASCII extended table but the hex bits are not the same as the answer on the book.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use a hex-to-decimal converter, not hex-to-ASCII.

Comment: And then convert to ASCII?

Comment: No. `cc` in hex equals 204 in decimal; `3e` in hex equals 62 in decimal, and so on. This is just math.